# NodeJS application with kue never stars from 0

Tags: node.js, redis, kue

I have a nodeJS api that uses kue to perform long running operations.

Although, once I shutdown the application and restart it all the previous jobs are still there. Removing them will not reset the redis counter to 0. Removes them only from any state: active, inactive, failed, complete or delayed.

here is my kue declaration:

```
var kue = require('kue'),
queue   = kue.createQueue()
```

Everytime certain api endpoint gets called I do the following:

```
//enqueue a new job process for data analysis
var daJob = queue.create('job1', {
    title: 'job to be completed'
}).removeOnComplete(true).save( function(err){
   if( !err ) res.json(daJob);
   else console.error(err);
});
```

How can I get kue to forget jobs once I restart my application?

I am using redis on windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1 :**

If you don't need the job records at all, you can simply run

```
redis-cli flushall
```

it will clear up the redis memory and you can begin from the start

**Option 2**

You can setup Kue UI and view all the jobs there, it has option to delete the jobs as well. Follow [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kue-ui) guide to setup Kue UI.